# Swift split strings efficiently

Tags: swift, string, split

I have a lot of strings like this one:

`"substring1:substring2:...:substring9"`

So the number of substrings in string is always 9, and some substrings in string may be empty.

I want to split the string by `":"` into array of strings and i do it like this:

`let separator = Character(":")`

`let arrayOfStrings = string.split(separator: separator, maxSplits: 8, omittingEmptySubsequences: false).map({ String($0) })`

For example for 13.5k strings it took about 150ms to convert them into arrays of strings.

Is there any other method that is more efficient in terms of time for this task?

Comment: `let arrayOfStrings = string.components(separatedBy: ":")` might be quicker, since you don't need a `map()` afterward (which is creating another loop).

Comment: Where do the strings come from, and how are the substrings used? Perhaps you can work with an array of `SubString` instead, and avoid the conversion to `String`.

Comment: I don't think it's the `split` which take a lot of time. `map` is very powerful but not very time-savior (remember that this will make a new object on every iteration)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 let arrayOfStrings = string.components(separatedBy: ":")
```

This should improve performance as it doesn't use `.map()`, which isn't really required in your case.

**Or**

As @Martin R suggested, if you can work with an array of `SubString` instead, the following should perform better:

```
let arrayOfStrings = string.split(separatedBy: ":")
```

`split` returns `[Substring]` which only uses references, does not allocate a new String and should be faster.
Also, `.split` is a method on `String`, (unlike `.component` which is a method on NSString) and hence there is no bridging conversion as pointed by @JeremyP.

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR. I have attempted to add an explanation.

Comment: The only thing I would say about this solution is that `components(separatedBy:)` is only available if you import `Foundation`. I'm wondering if it is an `NSString` method meaning that there are bridging conversions to take into account.

Comment: @JeremyP, do you think `.split(separatedBy:)` will work better?

Comment: @sasquatch Does that even exist? Do you mean `split(separator:)` because that is what the questioner is using and the hypothesis is that it is slow because of the need to convert the components to `String`